# Lambdify/Evaluate for given parameter values

Tags: python, sympy

Let's say I have a **symbolic** variable (as coming from `sympy`) defined as

```
z = r/p * (p-c)/(r-c)
```

More formally, denote this as `z=z(p; c, r)`: `c` and `r` are parameters that I want to hold constant, and `z` is really a function in `p`. 
Now, I want to evaluate `z=z(p)`, for chosen values of `c`, `r` -- but I don't want to define them within my `sympy` environment, because I want other expressions still to treat them as general and unknown parameters.

In essence, I'm looking for something like

```
my_func = lambdify(p, z(p), parameters={'r': 2, 'c': 1})
my_func(2)
Out: 1
z
Out: r/p * (p-c)/(r-c)
```

How could I perform such numerical evaluations?

Answer (score 1):

#### This might do what you want:

```
def my_lambdify(x, y, parameters=None):
    if parameters is not None:
        try:
            ys = y.subs(parameters)
        except ValueError:
            ys = y
    else:
        ys = y
    return lambdify(x, ys)

my_func = my_lambdify(p , z, parameters={'r': 2, 'c': 3})
```

#### Output:

```
my_func(2)
```

> 1.0

```
z
```

> r*(-c + p)/(p*(-c + r))

```
my_func = my_lambdify(p , z, parameters={'r': 'r0', 'c': 'c0'})
my_func(2)
```

> r0*(-c0 + 2)/(-2*c0 + 2*r0)